# predict text classification using python

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, predict

I want to predict a text classification which is based on the correlation of the text in the training data set.

For eg. This is my training data:
"Mouse M325",
"Mouse for xyz M325",
"M325 Mouse logitech",
"Logitech mouse number M325"

As it is visible that Mouse and M325 definitely have a high correlation when compared with M325 and Logitech or others.

I want to use the correlations to predict a classification for the next dataset.
For eg. If the next data is "**Mouse used by Alex number is M325**"...it should give me "**Mouse M325**" as text classifier and notify in a separate tab that the model has predicted this description but it was not something that Machine had seen earlier in trained data.
Like,[Result Model has predicted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBMa0.jpg) . How to solve this?

Comment: My suggestion is to use sklearn naive bayes.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Can you please guide me how to do it? I think it can be done by by k means clustering. Please guide or any link where something similar is done would be really helpful

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21298368/2661491) would be a good place to start, then maybe move to something fancier like TF-IDF

Comment: There is a huge lib on scikit (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html)